# Get Content type of HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm having trouble using HttpUrlConnection. I'm working on multiple servers. Some servers send response in gzip encoding and some don't. For gzip encoding, I'm using

```
inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
```

And for normal encoding, I'm using

`inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());`

Is it possible to know the encoding of getInputStream so that I know beforehand whether or not to use `GZIPInputStream`. Or is there a generic input stream reader for both compressed & uncompressed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the content encoding from the `HttpURLConnection` using [`getContentEncoding()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentEncoding--).

It it's gzip-encoded, the result of that call should be `gzip`, and then you know what type of input stream you need to create.